# Re-accessing random data between methods in ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

For my Swift app, I want the data accessed in the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` function to be from the same random column of data retrieved from the `viewDidLoad` function, which was done with `let randNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))`.  My app is a poll app where users can vote for different poll options then when they click the "Next" button, it takes them to another poll at random.  The code under the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` function is for adding the vote (and retrieving it) from a poll, but I need that poll to be the same one displayed by the `viewDidLoad` function.  How do I do that? For some reason no matter what poll I retrieve (crepes or pancakes, Coke or Pepsi, chocolate or vanilla, etc.) it only adds votes to and retrieves the results from the "crepes or pancakes" poll. Like if the user gets the poll "Coke or Pepsi" and they select Coke, it'll add a vote to the crepes vote count and retrieve the results from that poll.  How do I retrieve data from the poll that is retrieved?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
            query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (count: Int32, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    let randNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
                    query.whereKey("pollNumber", equalTo: randNumber)
                    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            NSLog("%@", error)
                        } else {
                            let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
                            let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
                            let option1 = voteCount1["optionName"] as String
                            let option2 = voteCount1["optionName2"] as String
                            self.showOption1.text = "\(option1)"
                            self.showOption2.text = "\(option2)"
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    println("error \(error)")
                }
            }

        }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var pollResults: UILabel!

@IBAction func addVote1(sender: AnyObject) {
    for button in self.buttons {
        button.enabled = false
    }
    var query = PFQuery(className: "VoteCount")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else {
            voteCount1.incrementKey("votes")
            voteCount1.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
            let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
            let votes2 = voteCount1["votes2"] as Int
            self.pollResults.text = "\(votes)                                                       \(votes2)"
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `randomNumber` a property instead of a local variable. However I think what you're actually trying to do is make sure you access the same `PFObject` in your later methods as you do in `viewDidLoad`. To do this, you don't need to re-fetch from Parse. Just keep a reference to the PFObject:

```
var voteCount : PFObject?
```

And in your completion block in viewDidLoad:

```
(voteCount1: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        NSLog("%@", error)
    } else {
        self.voteCount = voteCount1
        // The rest of your code...
        let votes = voteCount1["votes"] as Int
```

Then, later on, instead of fetching again, you just use the `voteCount` property:

```
@IBAction func addVote1(sender: AnyObject) {
    for button in self.buttons {
        button.enabled = false
    }

    voteCount.incrementKey("votes")
    voteCount.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
    let votes = voteCount["votes"] as Int
    let votes2 = voteCount["votes2"] as Int
    self.pollResults.text = "\(votes)                    \(votes2)"
}
```

Comment: Yes, I meant the code below the method.  If all of the code is below the viewDidLoad method, will the same value called at random by getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock be referenced the second time the getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock is implimented?  Or does it have to retrieve a different value?

Comment: If you use the same query it will be the same, but if that's what you want, just store the object you get back from the first call in a property.

Comment: How exactly do I make randNumber into a property? I thought I had already done so by making it a constant.

Comment: @hamza1234, if you create a constant inside a method, it's just a local constant that is not available outside that method. You make it a property by declaring it at outside of any method (usually at the top of the file, but it doesn't have to be) but inside the curly braces of the class definition.

Comment: Unfortunately now when I put let randNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count))) above the method inside the class definition, I get the bizarre error "Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type 'UInt32'".  I believe this may be an issue with Swift itself, since many others have experienced this for unknown reasons.

Comment: You're focusing on the random number but I think you actually want to store the result of the first query. I'll update my answer

Comment: I changed my code to the way you edited it in your answer, but it still only adds votes to the values from the first query, and retrieves those same values. Are you sure there's nothing that I should do with the randNumber?

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted to happen?

Comment: No, I'm trying to make the IBAction, addvote1, add the votes to the same query that's in the viewDidLoad method. Each time the page is accessed, that first query calls a different poll, and I just want the IBAction to add the votes to the poll that is called by that query. Right now the problem is that it adds votes to the same poll every time (and shows that one poll's results), regardless of which poll choices are called by the first query.

Comment: So you've removed the fetch from addVote1 method?

Comment: I didn't. There's no way for me to remove that query in IBAction without getting an error.

Comment: How do I remove the fetch from the IBAction and just make it so that it references the voteCount property instead?

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer, but it sounds to me like you don't really understand how the code you've got is currently working, and that you're probably going to struggle with the rest of this project without learning some basic object-oriented programming principles - I'd suggest doing some reading and basic tutorials before carrying on. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I could ask you to clarify one last thing, would I put the 'var voteCount : PFObject?' in the viewDidLoad method or outside of it?

Comment: Outside, to make it a property, otherwise it would be a local variable.